I'm getting and unhandled promise rejection that I need correct syntax for in nodejs
I've created a module that is pulling data from binance us api, but I can't seem to send that variable to any other file properly. I'm trying to create a function that pulls a variable each time it runs and send it to be used as a dynamic variable in another file.
This is my updated function code from discussions below in /modules/Tradepair.js:
async function getTradepair() {
  const apiUrl = "https://api.binance.us/api/v3/ticker/24hr";
  // Make a GET request
 let data ;
 try{
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
    if (!response.ok) {
       throw new Error("Network response for pair was not ok");
    }
     data = await response.json();
    //  console.log(data);

 } catch (error) {
     console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
}
  const max = data.reduce(
      (a, b) => (a.priceChangePercent > b.priceChangePercent ? a : b), data[0]);
  console.log(`Max Symbol from API: ${max.symbol}`);
  console.log(`Max Percent from API: ${max.priceChangePercent}`);
  const tradingPair = max.symbol;
  console.log(`Assigned to Trading pair variable: ${tradingPair}`);
  return tradingPair; // Return the tradingPair variable
}
module.exports = getTradepair;

This is the updated version from discussions below:
require("dotenv").config();
const Wolf = require("./modules/Wolf.js");
const getTradepair = require("./modules/Tradepair.js"); //file-name where you have defined this `getTradepair()` function.

async function getData() {
  try {
    const data = await getTradepair();
    console.log("From index:" + " " +data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
  }
}

const config = {
  // tradingPair: process.env.TARGET_ASSET + process.env.BASE_ASSET,
  tradingPair: getData(),
  profitPercentage: Number(process.env.PROFIT_PERCENTAGE) / 100,
  budget: Number(process.env.BUDGET),
  compound: process.env.COMPOUND.toLowerCase() === "true",
  profitLockPercentage: Number(process.env.PROFIT_LOCK_PERCENTAGE) / 100,
  stopLimitPercentage: Number(process.env.STOP_LIMIT_PERCENTAGE) / 100,
};

const wolf = new Wolf(config);

And this is the error I keep getting:
Max Symbol from API: VITEUSDT
Max Percent from API: 6.467
Assigned to Trading pair variable: VITEUSDT
From index: VITEUSDT
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "false".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}

Node.js v20.12.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...


Does your this module /modules/Tradepair.js contain the code about getTradepair() ?You have not even import it in a correct manner.
response of the your fetch() call is not returned in a correct way.That is why you are getting UnhandledPromiseRejection error.

Yes, the /modules/Tradepair.js contains the function getTradepair()
What is the correct way to import and setup the call to return in the correct way?

Hi I have posted my answer. Please check and let me know.

Before the Promise gets resolved this getData() is executed in a synchronous manner which is not a valid practice and that is why you are seeing this error.
After defining the getTradepair() as an async function import and execute this function like this.
const getTradepair = require('./modules/your-file-name'); //file-name where you have defined this `getTradepair()` function.

async function getData(){

 try {
        const data = await getTradepair();
        console.log(data);
        return data ;
     } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
     }

 }

 getData().then((data) => {

   const config = {
     // tradingPair: process.env.TARGET_ASSET + process.env.BASE_ASSET,
     tradingPair: data,
     profitPercentage: Number(process.env.PROFIT_PERCENTAGE)/100,
     budget: Number(process.env.BUDGET),
     compound: process.env.COMPOUND.toLowerCase() === "true",
     profitLockPercentage: Number(process.env.PROFIT_LOCK_PERCENTAGE)/100,
     stopLimitPercentage: Number(process.env.STOP_LIMIT_PERCENTAGE)/100

   };

   const wolf = new Wolf(config);

   console.log(wolf); // you can also console to see your expected result 

  } ).catch((error) => {

     console.error("Error:", error);

  });

Try the above code.I am sure you will not get this UnhandledPromiseRejection error. Still if it doesn't go along the way then please don't bother to ask for help.

Thanks, I'm not getting the unhandled Promise rejection yet. I'm getting the SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' which I tired resolving by installing express, but that doesn't seem to fix it.

Can you please tell me in which line of code it throws this error? I mean exactly which line of code throws this erro during execution? One thing you need to just replace the above code in place of your code keeping all other aspect same. The erro you are getting it is a syntax error though.

@DuaneBednorz , remove export  from export async function getTradepair()  and after the function defination either add export { getTradepair };  or module.exports = getTradepair;.I think it will resolve the issue.It is a ES6 compatibility issue.Try it and let me know.
`


export async function getTradepair() { - caused the syntax error
export {getTradepair};
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
module.exports = getTradePair; caused this -  Error fetching data: TypeError: fetch failed
SYMBOL ERROR:  fetch failed
node:internal/process/promises:289
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^


What is your node version??naming convention issue. It would be module. exports = getTradepair the name should be same as of the function name @DuaneBednorz

$ node -v
v20.12.1

I tried several different ways:
module. exports = getTradepair;
module. exports = getTradepair
module. exports = getTradepair()
module. exports = getTradepair();
Same error

@DuaneBednorz, Since there is this error TypeError: fetch failed while using module.exports = getTradePair; , I think there is some issue regarding fetching data.So I have implemented try-catch block inside getTradepair() so that in case of fetch() error it can be properly handled..pleas check my edited code and implement the code. Here module.exports = getTradePair; the name should be the same as of the function name means module.exports = getTradepair;.This code must be working.Please check and let me know.

@DuaneBednorz , another point to note that your code is working well. But the error you are getting is the error from your API endpoint. Because you are getting error starting with this Error fetching data which is written like so in the file where you declared const = config = {.. to capture error in case of any issue rageding API endpoint. So please check all related configuration regarding API endpoint. Code is working correctly but APi endpoint not sending data.

Updated - console logs are working, fetch error is gone, but:
node:internal/process/promises:289
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "false".] {
code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
Node.js v20.12.1

@DuaneBednorz , have used catch block after importing the function. Read my previous comment where I have clarified that previous version of the code was also working because it was throwing error from the catch block where you are fetching the data. Check my previous comment. I think API endpoint is sending data properly. Catch block was there to raise the error.

I've updated my current code above, I m no longer getting the Error from the catch block after the import, but still getting the unhandled promise rejection and the console logs are sending me the API data

I modifed my code to test the API config error:
async function getTradepair() {
tradingPair = "BTCUSDT";
return tradingPair;
}
module.exports=getTradepair;
The variable is passed through, but still the same error:
TradePair From index: BTCUSDT
| Initializing...node:internal/process/promises:289
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

@DuaneBednorz ,I am sorry It was my mistake. Before the Promise gets resolved this 'getData()' is executed in a synchronous manner that is why this you are seeing this error.
I am updating my answer the 2nd block of the code.Please do this ,it will work for sure.

@DuaneBednorz , I have updated the 2nd part of my answer. I enclosed the entire code in a Resolved Promise State.Try this ,it will work.Also this part of code is tested from my side.

@DuaneBednorz , If it resolve your issue then please plz accept my answer so that others can take guide from it who faces the similar problem.
